# How should I do interprocess communication between a management process and child processes?

Tags: java, process

I have five separate java **processes**; which are running as business logic modules. I would like to develop my process management application were i can **start/ping/monitor/message** child processes.

Also, it maybe sharing resources like cache etc with child processes over rest-ws or worst case rmi calls since requires additional overhead.

I was inclined toward webservice based api, which will keep sending information about business logic running within processes. The processes can be data churning, computation, notification process engines.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does 'running as modules' mean? Why do you think RMI is the worst case? Are you aware of jvisuamvm? And JMX?

Comment: I've edited the question, apologies for pasting question in haste. Also, i am completely aware of JMX and VisualVM for JVM monitoring, but i am not interested in JVM monitoring. It is kind of business application monitoring hope it explains...

Comment: The general idea you can use java in a cluster or you can switch to cloud computing. In the cluster you be able to use RMI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use JMX, and publish one or more MBeans.  Oracle has [documentation on it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/standard.html).  You can use the request information from the processes, or to send them signals to change their behavior.

The bare bones outline of what you would do is decide what methods you need to expose remotely in each of your child processes.  Each of them should define an interface with those methods, then an implementation of that interface.  Then those implementations need to be registered with the `MBeanServer`.

The advantage of this approach is that you will **immediately** get a bare-bones 'management application', because you can open JConsole against your processes and use the MBeans.  If you then wish to create a separate application that will more cleanly present your data, you can do so at your leisure, without changing the child processes.

This approach does not really get you anyway to 'sharing a cache', but sharing a cache between processes (or machines) should really be a separate question (I think).